# Pull request and merge actions in CI/CD

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, pull-request

The CI/CD pipeline supports pipelines per branch but no pipeline for feature branches is triggered automatically. There are pipelines deployed for the following branches: `development`, `master`. The respective pipeline is triggered `onCommit` event `(codeCommitRepo.onCommit('OnCommit', {})`  so whenever there is any code push to the branch. We are planning to use git-flow as the branching strategy but don't exactly see the advantages of having another branch called `staging`, in addition to `development`, `master`.

1. Is there a use of having a third branch like "staging" when using CI/CD?

The CI/CD pipeline looks as follows:

[image]

2. At what stage should the PR from the feature branch be created?
3. At what stage should the PR be merged into the development branch?
4. At what stage should the PR from the development branch to master be created?
5. At what stage should the PR be merged into the master branch?
6. What if the development pipeline fails? Should the code be manually unmerged to get development back in the stable condition?
7. What if the master pipeline fails?
   Is the code being merged in the branch after the pipeline succeeds?

I would like to understand what the flow should look like starting from a feature branch.  (P.S: Not interested in Trunk based development strategy)

Also, if I am maintaining a pipeline for the development branch and master branch each, That means I am building twice as well. The pipeline description says "create once, deploy many". Am I going in the wrong direction here?

Link to the CI/CD: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-simple-cicd

Comment: Could you please post the link to the CI/CD you are using? I saw it in your earlier posts, but now I can't find it.

Comment: @Marcin: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-simple-cicd

Comment: @Marcin please let me know if you need any further information. Look forward to your response

Comment: Sadly, I don't have any concrete answer yet.

Comment: "That means I am building twice as well" - if you stay within the Gitflow, there is no real work around here. If you move to TBD or some flavor of it, then you can change this.